# How to add multiple attributes to a single data row in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, attributes, addition

Can these attributes be combined to a single line of vb code?

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes.Add("id", "MyID")
e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes.Add("class", "MyCLASS")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using the framework. If you really need to do it one line, write a method...

```
AddIdAndClassToCell(e.Row.Cells(1), "MyId", "MyClass")

Private Sub AddIdAndClassToCell(cell, id, class)
    cell.Attributes.Add("id", id)
    cell.Attributes.Add("class", class)
End Sub
```

Or you could make a more generic helper...

```
Private Sub AddAttributes(cell, attributes As Dictionary(of String, String))
    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In attributes
        cell.Attributes.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's more code than I started with =) I actually have more than two attributes to add. I was just wondering if there was a shorthand way to just string another += add to the end of the line.

Comment: It may be more code but in the end that method can be reused and thus saving you the hassle of typing redundant lines of code. KISS